# problems with apex_json.get_number in restufl services

Tags: json, oracle, rest, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I am using the following lines of code in PL/SQL :

```
APEX_JSON.PARSE(  p_values => l_values, p_source => l_content , p_strict => false );

l_id:=APEX_JSON.GET_NUMBER(p_path=>'id',p0=> 1,p_values=>l_content);

UPDATE orders_ec ec SET id= l_id WHERE ec.secuencia=l_secuencia;
```

(where `l_content` is a clob with a json and `l_id` is an integer )
and it works fine,

but when I try to use it on a restful service (`ORDS-APEX`)

the result returns with a
**SQL Error Code** :

```
ORA-06550 : línea 18, columna 9: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call 
to 'GET_NUMBER' ORA-06550: línea 18, columna 3: PL/SQL: Statement ignored ...
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: APEX VERSION IS 19.2

Comment: Have you tried displaying the results of the `apex_json.parse` before passing its value to `apex_json.get_number`?

Comment: Hi oez, did you still need help with this or did Carsten’s answer work? If it worked, please accept the answer for future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

You passed the JSON text (l_content) into GET_NUMBER, however, it has to be the l_values variable, which represents the parsed JSON.

l_id:=APEX_JSON.GET_NUMBER(p_path=>'id',p0=> 1,p_values=>l_values);